# Automatically lock a file on checkout (VS2017 w/On Premises TFS)

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2017, locking, checkout, tfvc

My project recently migrated from VSS to TFS, and we are using TFVC for our main CM and documentation repo. In order to simplify things and reduce the system shock, we would like to automatically force a lock of files on check out. Is there a way to do this in a VS 2017 (On-Premises TFS setup)?

I have already tried this, and it doesn't work:

1. **Team->Team Project Collection Settings->Source
   Control...->Workspace Settings Tab**: Changed default workspace
   type from "Local (recommended)" to "Server".
2. Within **Team->Team Project Settings->Source Control...->Check-out Settings Tab**: Changed enable multiple check-out to UNchecked.

Lastly, I would like to apply the changes globally...I was hoping this would be a server configuration setting. Is this true, or does every single person on the team have to make local workspace changes?

Comment: You should re-evaluate your workflow. There's no reason to continue to use lock-based source control workflows when you have a tool that has support for lock-free workflows and, in fact, recommends that you use it that way by **making lock-free workflows the default behavior**.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the default type for new workspaces ([Manage project collection workspace settings for your team](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/decide-between-using-local-server-workspace?view=azure-devops#manage-project-collection-workspace-settings-for-your-team)) but any team member can update the type for own workspace. The option **enable multiple check-out** is applied to whole repository but using of a local workspace ignores this option ([When might I need to use a server workspace?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/decide-between-using-local-server-workspace?view=azure-devops#when-might-i-need-to-use-a-server-workspace)). There is no option to lock the workspace type.